# Prove that $BA^{-1} B \not=-B$ if $A + B$ is invertible for $A$ invertible and $B$ non-zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n×n$ real square matrices. Matrix $A$ is an invertible and $B$ is a non-zero matrix.

a)Prove that $BA^{-1} B \not=-B$ if $A + B$ is invertible

b) Let $B= uv^T$ for $u,v \in \Bbb R^n$. Prove that $BA^{-1}B=-B$ when  $v^TA^{-1}u= -1$

I'm kind of left in the dark with this problem. I tried applying trace and using the determinants (as $\det(A + B) = 0$ ), however I don't know how to proceed,

Comment: $BA^{-1}B=-B \Rightarrow BA^{-1}(A+B)=0\Rightarrow B=0 $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:
$$\begin{align}
BA^{-1}B+B & = B(A^{-1}B+I) = B(A^{-1}A)(A^{-1}B+I)\\
& = BA^{-1}(B+A)
\end{align}$$
Since $A+B$ and $A^{-1}$ are invertible and $B$ is nonzero, this matrix is nonzero. Therefore $BA^{-1}B+B \neq 0 \iff BA^{-1}B \neq -B$.

Comment: (The second question isn't really too hard, so I'll let you finish).

Comment: Ohh I see. Do you have any advice on how to tackle these kind of problems (that are easy, when knowing where to start)

Comment: @ŽanŽurič: My thought process here was to start with what I wanted to prove, write it in an easier form ($BA^{-1}B + B \neq 0$), and try to use the hypotheses as much as I could (so factoring to make something looking like $A+B$ appear, then using that $A$ was invertible...). But really, you should try your hand at as many exercises like that as possible, and then it'll come naturally to you.

Answer (score 1):

If $B = u v^T$ and $v^T A^{-1} u = -1$, then

$$B A^{-1} B = u \underbrace{v^T A^{-1} u}_{=-1} v^T = -u v^T = -B$$